# Frequent Copy-only full database backups running on SQL Server VM in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup

We got a 2019 SQL Server VM in Azure with both Azure Server backups and Azure SQL Database backups configured.

Azure SQL Database backups are configured as FULL backups on Sunday and DIFF backups the other 6 days but I noticed there are frequent (7 times a day) copy-only full backups running. These copy-only full backups only take 10-15 seconds but when they run, the I/O gets frozen and it's impacting the SQL performance during business hours.

I understand that as part of Azure SQL Server VM backup, it will trigger a copy-only full database backup (and we got VM Backups running at 10:00 pm, so the copy-only full backup at around 10:15 pm is related to this), but not sure what process is taking the other 6 copy-only full database backups (they run every 4 hours at 1:30 AM, 5:30 AM, 9:30AM, 1:30PM, 5:30PM, 9:30PM). Any ideas on where to look for in Azure configuration?

I have attached a screenshot of the backup history for one of the databases on the SQL Server. A normal FULL backup which runs on Sunday at 7:00 PM takes about 200 mins and DIFF backups which run the other 6 days at 7:00 pm take about 8-10 mins.

I would like to know what could be triggering these copy-only FULL backups so we can disable them. We don't have any other database backups configured (SQL Agent jobs or 3rd party tools like NetBackup, Veaam, CommVault etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Disable SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure for a specific database:

1. Connect to the Database Engine.
2. From the Standard bar, click **New Query**.
3. Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click Execute.

```
EXEC msdb.managed_backup.sp_backup_config_basic  
                @database_name = 'TestDB'   
                ,@enable_backup = 0;  
GO
```

Comment: I have run the below 2 queries to check the existing settings. The first query returns no records and second query returns only 1 record with '0' value under first column "is_managed_backup_enabled". So it looks like Managed Backups are not enabled.

SELECT * FROM msdb.managed_backup.fn_backup_db_config (NULL)
SELECT * FROM msdb.managed_backup.fn_backup_instance_config ()

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems a lot like expected behavior, based on my time around Azure VMs which happen to run SQL Server.

Looking over Microsoft's documentation for SQL Server backups fired off from Azure Backup, this is highlighted: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/faq-backup-sql-server#can-i-use-azure-backup-for-iaas-vm-as-well-as-sql-server-on-the-same-machine-

> Can I use Azure Backup for IaaS VM as well as SQL Server on the same machine?
>
> > Yes, you can have both VM backup and SQL backup on the same VM. In this case, we internally trigger copy-only full backup on the VM to not truncate the logs.

You're dead on the money that copy-only backups will run if there's Azure VM backups and SQL Server backups configured within Azure Backup, and this can certainly have impact on the overall IO of the server.

The interval is the part of this that piques my interest. Every four hours there's a full, copy-only backup, and per your statement - the only configured backup solution on the server is Azure Backup.

What do you see in the application/system event viewer logs at the time when these backups are taken? I expect that you will see additional invocation of the Azure WL Backup Plugin in the event viewer logs.

Can you confirm that there are no additional parameters with how you have your Azure Backup backups configured? Are you backing up the disks in addition to the VM? I know disks can have hourly backups set up, which might explain the frequency.

Comment: I did review the URL you posted and my assumption was that Azure will trigger an internal Copy-Only full backup when its running the VM backup (and I have counted out the one Copy-Only backup at 10:00 pm out of 7 copy-only backups happening daily). 

We don't have any additional backups configured (like disks).

We got a 2nd production VM in a different resource group but the same backup policies are configured for both VMs and I am not seeing this issue on the 2nd VM. I have compared the VM configuration and they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but we recently experienced the same thing and had it turn out to be related to SentinelOne agents, which by default will run VSS Snapshots every 4 hours. Disabling the S1 snapshots, resolved the issue for us.